# Why abort() method is called sometimes when I iterate over directory using std::filesystem::directory_terator?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++17, abort, std-filesystem

I am creating a simple file watcher in C++. I am using `std::filesystem::directory_iterator` and sometimes it crashes with `abort()` being called. It works perfectly when I track creating and editing of files (which is not strange, because for that I use `map::iterator`). But when I need to track deleting and renaming of the file, `directory_iterator` tends to crash sometimes.

The thing is, it can work for several times and then crash. And the number of times is always different. I have already commented out the code that can possibly cause the problem, so the problem is definitly in the `directory_iterator`. What can possibly be the problem?

Here is the header of the file, if it's relevant

```cpp
#ifndef FILEWATCHER_H
#define FILEWATCHER_H
#include <map>
#include <filesystem>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

class FileWatcher
{
    size_t currentNumberOfFiles = 0;
    fs::path pathToWatch;
    std::map<fs::path, fs::file_time_type> pathsMap;
    std::string currentTime();
public:
    FileWatcher(fs::path path);
    void start();
};

#endif
```

And the .cpp file:

```cpp
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
#include "FileWatcher.h"
#include "Event.h"
#include <iostream>

std::string FileWatcher::currentTime()
{
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::time_t nowTime = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
    std::string currentSystemTime = std::ctime(&nowTime);
    return currentSystemTime;
}

FileWatcher::FileWatcher(fs::path pathToWatch)
{
    this->pathToWatch = pathToWatch;
    //create a map with last modification of a given file in the directory
    for (auto& file : fs::directory_iterator(this->pathToWatch))
    {
        pathsMap.emplace(file.path(), fs::last_write_time(file));
    }
}

void FileWatcher::start()
{
    while (true)
    {
        currentNumberOfFiles = std::distance(fs::directory_iterator(pathToWatch), fs::directory_iterator());
        
        auto it = pathsMap.begin();
        while (it != pathsMap.end())
        {
            if (!fs::exists(it->first.string()))
            {
                if (currentNumberOfFiles < pathsMap.size())
                {
                    //file deleted
                    //FileType fileType = (fs::is_regular_file(it->first) ? FileType::FILE : FileType::DIRECTORY);
                    //Event event(EventType::DELETED, fileType, it->first, currentTime());
                    //event.printEvent();
                    std::cout << "Remove" << std::endl;
                    it = pathsMap.erase(it);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {

                    //file is renamed
                    //ileType fileType = (fs::is_regular_file(it->first) ? FileType::FILE : FileType::DIRECTORY);
                    //Event event(EventType::RENAMED, fileType, it->first, currentTime());
                    //event.printEvent();
                    std::cout << "Renamed" << std::endl;
                    it = pathsMap.erase(it);
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                it++;
            }
        }

        for (auto& file : fs::directory_iterator(pathToWatch))
        {
            if (pathsMap.count(file.path()) == 0)
            {

                //file is create
                pathsMap.emplace(file.path(), fs::last_write_time(file));
                //FileType fileType = (fs::is_regular_file(file) ? FileType::FILE : FileType::DIRECTORY);
                //Event event(EventType::CREATED, fileType, file.path(), currentTime());
                //event.printEvent();
                std::cout << "Created" << std::endl;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if (pathsMap[file.path()] != fs::last_write_time(file))
                {

                    //file is modified
                    //pathsMap.emplace(file.path(), fs::last_write_time(file));
                    pathsMap[file.path()] = fs::last_write_time(file.path());
                    //FileType fileType = (fs::is_regular_file(file.path()) ? FileType::FILE : FileType::DIRECTORY);
                    //Event event(EventType::EDITED, fileType, file.path(), currentTime());
                    //event.printEvent();
                    std::cout << "Modified" << std::endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I will also attach the `abort()` message which is produced:

[image: abort() message]

Visual Studio 2019 doesn't produce any errors to the output log.

Comment: ["A file system race is the condition that occurs when multiple threads, processes, or computers interleave access and modification of the same object within a file system.
Behavior is undefined if calls to functions provided by subclause \[filesystems\] introduce a file system race."](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/fs.race.behavior#1)

Comment: @cpplearner, but I don’t use threads or anything mentioned in the link.

Comment: If your program is running, then you do use "processes, or computers".

Comment: *What can possibly be the problem.* -- The debug message box has 3 buttons.  Did you hit "Retry"?  Did you or are you attached to the process with the debugger, used "Break All", and check the call stack to see which series of calls caused the error?  The answer to "what can be the problem" will be known if you followed those steps.

Comment: That `start` member function does *a lot* of work...

Answer (score 0):

You are experience a file system race, I think. Consider your two inner loops in the `start` method. The first one checks to see whether a single file has been renamed or removed (because you break out of the loop the moment you find either case), while the second loop checks to see whether any files were created or modified.

However, what happens if a file is removed (by another process) while the second loop is in action?

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator)

> If a file or a directory is deleted or added to the directory tree after the directory iterator has been created, it is unspecified whether the change would be observed through the iterator.

This behaviour is consistent with the POSIX [`readdir_r`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/readdir_r.html).

In short, what this means is that you need to be able to handle when files change mid-iteration. Probably, the `abort` is called because [`std::filesystem::last_write_time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/last_write_time) throws `std::filesystem::filesystem_error` when the file does not exist, which you may not have caught. You can either catch the exception or you can supply the additional `std::error_code` argument to `last_write_time`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, using try/catch block seems to work fine. But you mentioned supplying additional ```std::error_code``` to ```last_write_time```. What is it and how do I do it?

Comment: There are two overloads for `last_write_time` (check [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/last_write_time)), one of them takes two arguments. You just need to create a variable using `std::error_code` and pass it in as the second argument to `last_time_write`. You should check to see whether the error code is non-zero (you can cast it to a `bool` or call the `value()` method on it). If it is non-zero, then an error has occurred, otherwise, you can safely use the result of the call to `last_write_time`.